# Python and Regex with special characters

Tags: regex

I can't get my regex to work as desired in my Python 3 code.

I am trying to parse a file find a specific pattern (the exact pattern is Total Optimized)

I am doing this because the file can contain lines which say """Total Optimization (Active)""" and other permutations.  I have tried the following lines.  None work

```
PkOp = re.compile(r'Total Optimized\t\d')
PkOp = re.compile(r'Total Optimized\t\d')
PkOp = re.compile(r'Total Optimized\t[^(Active)]')
```

My basic code (which is simplified here) to just print the matching line out.  If I got that working I would then choose the array item I wanted such as

```
PkOp = PkOpArray[4]

App = re.compile(r'Appliance\s(Active)')
PkOp = re.compile(r"Total Optimized\t\d")
with open("SteelheadMetric2.txt","r") as f:
    with open("mydumbfile.txt","w") as o:
       for line in f:
          line = line.lstrip()
          matches = PkOp.findall(line)
          for firestick in matches:
                 PkOpArray = line.split()
                 PkOp = PkOpArray
                 print(PkOp)
```

Mostly I get this error

```
matches = PkOp.findall(line)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

If I remove the slash characters I can get it to show lines with 'Total Optimization' or 'Appliance' whatever.  I just can't be more specific in what I want.

What am I missing?  It works fine if I just compile a text string but to use special regex like whitespace, tab digit it fails.  The regex checks out in notepad++

Comment: When you write `PkOp = PkOpArray` you have just changed your `regex` into a `list`.

Comment: First thing to try is probably to delete that line, and change your `print` to `print(PkOpArray)`.

Comment: merlin you are a genuis!  I am just to tired  Been at this Python all day and just missed a step and reused my regex variable value in my code.  And kept doing it and doing...

Comment: I'm glad that fixed the problem. I will write it into an answer, for more permanence.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `PkOp = PkOpArray` you have just changed your regex into a `list`.

If you delete that line, and change your `print(PkOp)` to `print(PkOpArray)`, it should fix your problem, assuming the rest of your code is correct.